# Using dynamic with Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic

I've seen a few questions on here of people asking for criticism of their unit tests.  I haven't seem them get closed, so I'd like to do the same.

I whipped up these tests, which I believe are made more readable by using `dynamic`, but I was wondering if anyone in the SO community had anything to add.

I know the use of dynamic is for some reason very controversial, and for some reason starts religious wars amongst C# developers.  I'm really hoping to avoid that; I'm just trying to write some good tests to help me do my job :)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAllocation() {
        SearchView.StubPropertyNumValueThenSetUpSearchView<WellDetail>("TX", Property.WorkingInterestTaxSubtypeId);
        Presenter.SetUpPhaseAndFmvValues(Phase.PhaseIdForForRenderAppraiser, 1000);

        AddTheseItems(
            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 10 },
            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 10 },
            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 10 },
            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 10 },

            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can2", MostRecentFmv = 40 },
            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can2", MostRecentFmv = 40 },
            new { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can2", MostRecentFmv = 40 },

            new { PropNum = "pn2", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 50 },
            new { PropNum = "pn2", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 50 });

        Presenter.Process(SearchView, ItemsToProcess);

        AssertTheseItemsExist(
            new { NumberOfTimes = 4, PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can1", FmvCalculated = 100 },
            new { NumberOfTimes = 3, PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can2", FmvCalculated = 400 },
            new { NumberOfTimes = 2, PropNum = "pn2", CAN = "can1", FmvCalculated = 500 });
    }

    private void AddTheseItems(params dynamic[] MassUpdateDtos) {
        foreach(dynamic item in MassUpdateDtos)
            ItemsToProcess.Add(new MassFMVUpdateDTO(new WellDetail() { PropertyNum = item.PropNum, CountyAccountNum = item.CAN }, new FMVHistory(), 0, item.MostRecentFmv));
    }

    private void AssertTheseItemsExist(params dynamic[] uniqueTargets) {
        foreach (dynamic target in uniqueTargets)
            Assert.AreEqual(target.NumberOfTimes, ItemsToProcess.Count(f => f.PropertyNum == target.PropNum && f.CountyAccountNum == target.CAN && f.FMV == target.FmvCalculated));
    }
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `dynamic` in your case?

Comment: Overall I find not problem with this and I lean anti-dynamic. The question I would ask is, did you really save anything by not creating a little private class with auto properties for PropNum, CAN, etc.? You still are tightly coupled between the creation of the anonymous types and their usage and the compiler won't help you out. If your good with that, and your team is good with that then go for it.

Comment: @Daniel I think it just makes the tests a lot more readable; it focuses them on the particular data pieces that are relevant. The AddTheseItems method shows how bloated the test would be if I were to use the proper, statically typed objects (IMO).

Comment: @Mike I lean strongly against private classes for uses like that - I think they just bloat things, but that's purely a matter of personal preference. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @Adam: Your `AddTheseItems` would only be longer by the name of your class: `new Params { PropNum = "pn1", CAN = "can1", MostRecentFmv = 10 },`

Comment: @Daniel, yes, my *call* to AddTheseItems would only be longer by the name of the class — new privateTestClass() { PropNum = "pn1" etc — I just thought dynamic would be a good way to avoid having to put together a private class just for testing in the first place.  I thought dynamic + anon object would be a good way to minimize bloat.

Comment: @Adam - agree that it can feel like bloat. But the trade off is intellisense and compiler checking. Also with things like Resharper I can put that class together in seconds. But, it is true, it all comes down to personal preference. So you feel your big win with this technique is less bloat? Perfectly good with that, just clarifying.

Comment: @Adam: I don't really see a problem in using dynamic like this, it's basically just not used the way it was intended to, so I personally wouldn't use it like this but go with the private class...

Comment: @Mike, fair enough, thank you.

Comment: @Daniel - am I correct in assuming that the intended use of dynamic was an alternative to reflection, and for comm interop?

Answer (score 2):

Sure the use of dynamic reduces the lines of code you need to use. But think about what you want from unit tests first. You want them to tell you where your code goes wrong.

If one of the rows of data you add are wrong, will it tell you which one failed?
And if one of the asserts fails, will it tell you which one?

So long as you can get the information you need, you should be fine. So it should tell exactly what went wrong and when it did.

Comment: +1 That's a good point.  From what I can tell neither how I have it now, nor how it would be if I added in simple classes to avoid dynamic would tell me specifically which row caused the failure.  For me I expect the test to pass far, far more than I expect it to fail, so I figure I can just step into the test if I ever refactor my code such that the test breaks.  Does that sound like decent reasoning?

Comment: Exactly, you write the unit tests too detect bugs, when they do that you want them to show you where the bug is.